# Tiempo de ejecución de la CPU

Tags: python, linux

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo calcular el tiempo de CPU o tiempo de utilización de CPU en el sistema operativo Linux.

Sé que la información proviene del siguiente fichero `/proc/stat` y de la primera linea del fichero:

> **cpu  192369 7119 480152 122044337 14142 9937 26747 0 0**

¿Alguien sabe cuál sería la fórmula para obtener el tiempo de utilización de la CPU?

Comment: Es amplia tu pregunta, cómo pensas consumir esa información? Shell script, python, C?

Comment: en python estoy haciendo el script

Comment: [Este](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67904/calculate-cpu-by-process-from-proc-stat-and-proc-pid-stat) enlace te puede ayudar:

Comment: La otra posibilidad es una muy útil libreria: [Psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/4.3.0)

Comment: no puedo utilizas esa libreria  Psutil ya que el script esta dentro de un router tengo que hacer yo los calculos

Comment: Entonces el enlace anterior te va a ser más útil

Comment: Gracias nuevamente pero lo que no entiendo bien son las diferencias de tiempo que dicen - For real time CPU usage, you will need to calculate the time between two intervals. Que relación tiene esa diferencia de tiempos con la formula que ellos describen

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a pasar en limpio algunas cosas:

- Queres saber los tiempos de CPU accediendo directamente a `/proc/stats`
- `/proc/stats` tiene varios valores que son acumulativos desde el boot del equipo
- Si necesitás saber "ahora" como es el consumo de la CPU hay que tomar un intervalo de tiempo, por ejemplo, digamos 1 segundo, leemos los valores y luego de un segundo volvemos a leer, la diferencia entre ambas lecturas la podemos considerar como el estado actual de la CPU.
- Para entender qué son los distintos valores y como calcular el "tiempo de cpu", esta bueno el [enlace](https://github.com/Leo-G/DevopsWiki/wiki/How-Linux-CPU-Usage-Time-and-Percentage-is-calculated) que te pasó pmdelatorre
- Según esa documentación la fórmula para calcular el tiempo de uso de la cpu sería: `user+nice+system+irq+softirq+steal`
- No sé si el tiempo de CPU termina aportando algo, suele ser más útil saber el porcentaje de utilización, la formula sería `(user+nice+system+irq+softirq+steal)` / `(user+nice+system+idle+iowait+irq+softirq+steal)` * 100
- No podes usar librerías adicionales tipo **Psutil** por lo que obviamente deberías leer e interpretar el archivo /proc/stats para obtener esta info
- En [este](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67904/calculate-cpu-by-process-from-proc-stat-and-proc-pid-stat) enlace tenés una buena explicación de como hacerlo y varios ejemplos

De todas formas para clarificar te copio un ejemplo sencillo:

```
import time
def cpu_time():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        # count from /proc/stat: user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irc, softirq, steal, guest, guest_nice
        user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irq, softirq, steal, _, _ = tuple([float(i) for i in cputimes.split(' ')[2:]])

        cpu = user+nice+system+irq+softirq+steal
        total = user+nice+system+idle+iowait+irq+softirq+steal

        return((cpu, total))

scpu, stotal = (cpu_time())

import time
time.sleep(1)

ecpu, etotal = (cpu_time())

print("Tiempo de cpu (último segundo): {} porcentaje: {}".format((ecpu-scpu), (ecpu-scpu)/(etotal-stotal) * 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero puedes obtener el tiempo de ejecución de un programa, usando el comando time seguido del nombre del programa a ejecutar.

Con el siguiente formato: `time [programa]`

En la salida de ese comando, se te muestran 3 valores: real, user y sys.
Si no recuerdo mal, estos indicaban lo siguiente:

- real es el tiempo total desde que el programa empezó hasta que terminó su ejecución
- user es el tiempo que el programa ha estado realmente usando la CPU
- sys es el tiempo que ha empleado el sistema en cargar el proceso en la CPU, lo que se podría decir como el tiempo empleado en cambios de contexto