# Como obtener % de uso de CPU de un script de python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de ver la diferencia de consumo entre varios scrips de python, quisiera saber como ver el consumo de cpu sin necesidad de herramientas de monitorizacion (como htop en ubuntu) ya que los scrips se ejecutan de una forma demasiado rápida y no alcanzo a verlos en este tipo de herramientas. Es por esto que busco una forma de implementar estas medidas desde el mismo scrip de python.

Se que existe

```
psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

de la librería psutil, sin embargo este método solo devuelve el uso **global** de cpu mas no el del scrip de python que se esta ejecutando.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿conoces el paquete [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/profile.html)? Es nativo de Python y te da estadísticas, tiempos de ejecución, consumo de memoria y otros.

Comment: [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67138/183782) te puede servir

Comment: @Christian Hola, gracias por el link, ntente implementar el método de el ejemplo que me pasaste en lo que tengo actualmente, sin embargo los valores no son muy lógicos, ya que arroja un uso de memoria de entre 29% a 31%, mientras que en un script similar (el cual si pude llegar a medir en el software de monitorizacion htop) me arrojaban valores de entre 0.7% a 1.3%, por lo que no se si esta bien implementado dicho ejemplo o soy yo el que este fallando en algun aspecto.